# How download files from a html form R

Tags: html, r, web-services, web

when I press ctrl+s and save this page on my web browser

[http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?zma00944+default%3dred+cpd:C01514+cpd:C05903+cpd:C01265+cpd:C01714](http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?zma00944+default%3dred+cpd%3aC01514+cpd%3aC05903+cpd%3aC01265+cpd%3aC01714)

I download the html form and a folder with some png files. I'm interested in png files that have a known pattern.

Is there a way to download them in the same way from R?

I'm trying:

```
 download.file("http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?zma00944+default%3dred+cpd:C01514+cpd:C05903+cpd:C01265+cpd:C01714","form.html", mode = "wb")
```

but I download only the html form, not the associated pngs.

Thanks

Comment: The Bioconductor [pathview](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/pathview.html) package might help here, see it's [vignette](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/pathview/inst/doc/pathview.pdf)

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried the package, I even looked the code. It seems that it download the xml, look the metabolite coordinates and color the png. It is nice but is too slow for my application. Using kegg url scheme is much faster. I also looked kegg api and it seems they don't have a function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you part of the way there:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("KEGGREST")
library(png)
library(KEGGREST)
png <- keggGet(c("zma00944","default=red","cpd:C01514","cpd:C05903","cpd:C01265","cpd:C01714"), "image")
t <- tempfile()
writePNG(png, t)
browseURL(t)
```

Unfortunately it does not do the red highlighting which you probably want. I'm not sure if that can be done through the REST API.

So probably instead you could just download the URL as you have, and then parse it for the PNG and then download that:

```
download.file("http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?zma00944+default%3dred+cpd%3aC01514+cpd%3aC05903+cpd%3aC01265+cpd%3aC01714", "form.html")
lines <- readLines("form.html")
imgUrl <- lines[grep('img src="/', lines)]
url <- paste0("http://www.kegg.jp/", strsplit(imgUrl, '"')[[1]][2])
download.file(url, "file.png")
browseURL("file.png")
```

Comment: Excelent, thanks Dan, it is obvious, the link for the png will be on the html form. This will really speed my task...